# Disputed flag on closed question for same reason

Tags: discussion, flags

I have a scenario where a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894434/how-to-hashmap-an-array-in-java) has *been put on hold as unclear what you're asking* yet my flag was **disputed** even though the flag was *unclear what you're asking*.

My question is how does this actually get disputed. Should this not fall into a scenario where the flag is actually helpful, or is this a case of circumstances. If so is there a way to avoid it other then stop raising flags?

Comment: `My question is how does this actually get disputed` It got [reviewed](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8479031) as "Should Be Improved" in the Triage queue

Comment: Gah another "Should Be Improved" review.  When will it end?

Comment: Yes get to 3k ;) close votes trump Triage